# Как добавить локальный сервер в unit-тесты?

Tags: c#, asp.net-core, юнит-тесты

Помогите разобраться, как можно добавить локальный [сервер](https://www.npmjs.com/package/local-web-server)  к Unit-тестам (xUnit) в виде [Moq](https://www.nuget.org/packages/Moq/) объекта?

Мне необходимо добиться того, чтобы при запуске тестах на другом ПК (на котором не установлен nmp и ws), они (тесты) могли отправить запрос (GET, POST) на данный локальный [сервер](https://www.npmjs.com/package/local-web-server), так как в них (в тестах) прописаны пути до файлов данного сервера, возможно ли такое вообще реализовать?

Comment: Если тесты взаимодействуют с каким-то внешним сервером, то их уже нельзя называть unit-тестами

Comment: Поднимайте в тестах отдельный сервер, тогда и проблемы на другом компьютере не будет.

Comment: @XelaNimed могли бы Вы привести минимальный пример, как это сделать?
Или вы имеете ввиду HttpClient в C#?